# How to generate ebooks locally in windows using gitbook.io editor

Tags: gitbook

I'm using `Gitbook v 1.1.0` on windows and created a book. How do I now generate static html, PDF and epubs. I don't see any GUI options to see that.

Windows 7 and windows 8
Gitbook version: 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out `gitbook editor` and `gitbook` command for building files are separate projects

Project `gitbook` can be found here https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook and it requires `nodejs` and `calibre ebook management`

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer.